# Rmarkdown latex error for an enumerated environment

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have an Rmd document with R code chunks in between enumerated latex environment. While Knitting the document, an error is encountered at the code evaluation: `pSeq <- read.GenBank("NC_00111")`.

I am getting the following error with the code below:

````
\begin{enumerate}

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library('ape')

```

\textit{R functions: read.GenBank, ...}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item the accession number NC\_00111. \newline
    \textit{ only the sequence ...)}

```{r}
pSeq <- read.GenBank("NC_00111")

```
    \item ...

  \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
````

Error message:

```
! Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> 
                $ l.158 chimpSeq <- read.GenBank("NC_
                                   00111")
```

I am not sure how to overcome this error using the [solution provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415473/rmarkdown-xelatex-missing-inserted). Are there any other workarounds or solutions?

Comment: One option would be to end the enumerate, place the R code, and the re-start the enumerate after the code.  [Here's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142/how-can-i-make-an-enumerate-list-start-at-something-other-than-1) how to re-start the numbering with a "fresh" enumerate environment.

Comment: @DanY Thank you. I would check this one! I would need to check this with nested environments and compare.