# Rmarkdown fails at using xelatex engine

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, xelatex, tinytex

I am trying to specify a font style in my document and I found out I should use a specific latex engine: `xelatex`. However when I specify the following instruction inside the YAML header:

```
---
title: BLABLA - me
output:
  pdf_document: default
  engine: xelatex
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fontspec}
  - \setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
fontsize: 12pt
---
```

I could not get my document compiled because of the error:

```
    ! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
(fontspec)                      LuaTeX.
(fontspec)                      
(fontspec)                      You must change your typesetting engine to,
(fontspec)                      e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of
(fontspec)                      "latex" or "pdflatex".
```

I have installed the package `tinytex` and I do not know much about latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your header. Some posts (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105808/rmarkdown-pdf-latex3-error-erroneous-variable)) report that the correct way to specify engine is

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
```

Comment: Yes I am sorry. Do you know any way to change the title font to another one? such as Helvetica

Comment: That sounds like another question.